# Find difference between two timestamps then sum total time in each state

Tags: date, time, aggregate-functions, tableau-api

I have data showing timestamps and event titles at those times. I need to first calculate the duration between each event and then I need a total time for each event type.

[image: data source]

I've found the difference between the events by using DATEDIFF and LOOKUP like so:
[image: formula]

The problem I am running into now is how to get the total time spent in the "token auth succeeded" state and the total time spent in "closed connection" state

Comment: You might be able to answer a question like this with LOD calculations, but it may take some playing around...For these time of irregular times series questions, I would recommend doing the calculations in something like python first to get additional column on duration, and then put back into tableau.

Comment: I could not find a good way to do it in Tableau, so I made the calculation at the data level like you suggested.